# Java Interface Double Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

So, let's say that I have a java interface energy:

```
public Interface IEnergyNetwork {

    Voltage getVoltage();

    Resistance getResistance();

    Current getCurrent();
}
```

What each method returns is pretty obvious.

Now imagine that I have two classes that implement this same interface, being one class the class that matters, and the other class just a dummy security thing (if anything goes wrong with my program, like a bug or something).

Dummy class:

```
public class DummyEnergyNetwork implements IEnergyNetwork {

    @Override
    public Voltage getVoltage(){
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Resistance getResistance(){
    return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Current getCurrent(){
    return null;
    }

}
```

The class that I will work with:

```
public class EnergyNetwork implements IEnergyNetwork{
    @Override
    public Voltage getVoltage(){
    //work with the code that I need
    }

    @Override
    public Resistance getResistance(){
    //work with the code that I need
    }

    @Override
    public Current getCurrent(){
    //work with the code that I need
    }
}
```

Now, If I want to call, for exemple, the method getCurrent() from another class, by doing this:

```
public class PowerGenerator {

    public void addPower(double power){
        IEnergyNetwork network = new DummyEnergyNetwork();
        double current = network.getCurrent().size(); //assuming that the type current has a method that returns its value in double
        //do the rest of the code
    }
}
```

My doubt is which return will I have: the null one from DummyEnergyNetwork class or the Current one from EnergyNetwork class?

By the way, this is an adaptation from some code that I saw on Github from the Minecraft mod Botania. If you have trouble understanding my example, the source of my problem is under the class SubTileFunctional (https://github.com/Vazkii/Botania/blob/master/src/main/java/vazkii/botania/api/subtile/SubTileFunctional.java).

Comment: _new DummyEnergyNetwork();_ Why do you think `EnergyNetwork` is in any way involved?

Comment: Because, in the code that I'm studying, the class, which in this case is EnergyNetwork, if the class that makes the things needed for the code to work, not the dummy class.

Comment: Please rephrase that. I don't understand.

Comment: In the code that I'm studying, the dummy class returns either null or an empty arrayList. The other class is the one that executes the needed methods. But, according to what you just sayed, the methods are called from the dummy class, meaning that the methods called would be useless (If you still didn't understand, please check the class that I putted in my question + related classes [The method is called "linkPool()"]).

Comment: You need to read about polymorphism.

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. If I translate it from the code that I'm studying to my example above, when the program is initiating, the reference to the object DummyEnergyNetwork (network) is replaced by the actual reference that I needed (it basically transforms a  [IEnergyNetwork network = new DummyEnergyNetwork();] into a [ IEnergyNetwork network = new EnergyNetwork();]. It was my mistake because I hadn't seen the whole code yet).

Answer (score 2):

> My doubt is which return will I have: the null one from
>   DummyEnergyNetwork class or the Current one from EnergyNetwork class?

```
IEnergyNetwork network = new DummyEnergyNetwork();
```

as the reference `network` points to `DummyEnergyNetwork` so DummyEnergyNetwork methods will be invoked.

Comment: But, in that other code, the dummy class' methods return either null or an arrayList and the other class returns the variables necessary (see the class that I putted in my question and related classes, if you don't get what I'm saying).